# Building a Conveyor

Tags: physics

How would I build a Conveyor like [this](http://www.helloluxx.com/tutorials/cinema4d-2/cinema4d-dynamics/building-a-conveyor-with-cinema4d-dynamics/) in blender?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Rigid Body physics with [Constraints](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Rigid_Body_Joint) to replicate this:

1. Add a cylinder and make it an active Rigid Body object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Add a cube and make it a passive rigid body object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), and move it to the side of the cylinder.
3. Constrain them together (*Tool shelf > Rigid Body Tools > Connect*) with *Hinge* constraint and rotate the resulting empty 90 degrees on the Y axis:

   [image]
4. Constrain again with a *Motor* constraint and enable angular motor:

   [image]
5. Duplicate

[image]

Comment: Cool. What about making it follow a curve like in that video. The conveyor ain't straight.

Comment: @00Ghz You could use some of the techniques [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-to-keep-the-vertex-normals-after-deleting-an-edge-face), using an plane with *array* and *curve* modifiers as the emission mesh.

Comment: @gandaf3 same way i have my question but nobody answered it can u plz answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66456/how-a-physics-motor-and-slider-works